# How to create clear search url in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

My URL now looks like:

```
 http://146.185.xx.xx/search/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=the
```

I want to make it like:

```
http://146.185.xx.xx/search/the
```

How can I make it?

My Post.rb;

```
def self.search(query)
    where("title like ?", "%#{query}%")
end
```

My form in views:

```
form action="/search/<%= params[:search] %>" method="get" class ="navbar-form navbar-right" role ="search")
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_field_tag :search, nil, placeholder: "Найти посты", :class => "form-control", :pattern=>".{3,}" %>
    <%= submit_tag "OK", :name => nil, :class => "search_btn" %>
  </div>
</form>
```

Routes: `get "/search" => "posts#index"`

Comment: don't use `form_tag` use `<form action="<%= search_path %>" method="get"></form>`

Comment: anyone else can help me?

Answer (score 0):

don't use `form_tag` use

```
<form action="<%= search_path %>" method="get"></form>
```

or you can set

```
<%= form_tag('/search/', :method => "get", :enforce_utf8 => false %>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I get now `search/?search=the`. How can I get just `the` without `?search=`?

Comment: haven't you specified `:name => nil` on submit tag

Comment: I did: `text_field_tag :search, nil, placeholder: "Найти посты", :class => "form-control", :pattern=>".{3,}"`

Comment: I did. You can look now